# How can you remove XML escaped characters from a stored JSP (JSTL) variable?

Tags: jsp, jstl, html-escape

I'm trying to compare the values of two strings in a jsp file.  Both of these strings contain an apostrophe `'`.  These strings some from different sources.

When I directly compare the two strings like this:

```
<c:if test="${ fn:toLowerCase(colorInfo.value.name) eq fn:toLowerCase(colorName) }">
    hello!
</c:if>
```

the comparison returns a false.  When I print out the two values, however, I see

> Mike's Green
>
> Mike's Green

in a previous step, these strings are trimmed to this is not a whitespace issue.  For whatever reason, when stored as variables, one of these two is stored with an xml escaped apostrophe

```
&#39;
```

To prove this, I modified the comparison to the following:

```
<c:set var="apostrophe" value="'" />

<%-- I'm multilining this purely for readability on SO, it's 1 line in the code --%>
<c:if test="${ 
    fn:replace(fn:toLowerCase(colorInfo.value.name), '&#39;', apostrophe) 
    eq 
    fn:replace(fn:toLowerCase(colorName), '&#39;', apostrophe) 
}">
    hello!
</c:if>
```

This comparison returns true.  Therefore, one of the two strings has a literal xml escape'd version of apostrophe while being stored.

**Is there a more efficient way to escape any xml strings within a stored jsp variable?**  This is a very ugly way of doing the comparison, and it's not easily scalable as if future strings have other characters that are escaping improperly, then I will need to add more code to this logic.

Comment: You'd better fix the problem at the source where this data is coming from.

Comment: I am not in control of that, and I feel like it's good practice to have any issues handled at both ends.  I will be working with another team on resolving the issue on their end, but if in the future their stuff stops working I want my code to be able to handle it.

Comment: You can unescape using commons lang.